# mysqli_num_rows generates unlimited amount of data

Tags: php, mysqli

so, I'll try to explain it as good as I can with my knowledge in english.
I am trying to count data from my database, basically - how many fields I have with the same ID. here's image from database.

[image from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpStO.png)

for example, in posts i have review system and it works, i have this PHP code to count how many same fields i have with review and id.
Here's the code:

```
    <?php
$revposid = $res['content_id'];
$pos="SELECT review FROM comments WHERE review='positive' and postid=$revposid";
$neg="SELECT review FROM comments WHERE review='negative' and postid=$revposid";
$neu="SELECT review FROM comments WHERE review='neutral' and postid=$revposid";
if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$pos)){$rowcountpos=mysqli_num_rows($result);}
if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$neg)){$rowcountneg=mysqli_num_rows($result);}
if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$neu)){$rowcountneu=mysqli_num_rows($result);}
?>



<div class="reviews" id="reviews">
    <span class="good"><b class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></b><?php echo $rowcountpos ?></span> 
    <span class="neutral"><b class="icon-thumbs-up"></b><?php echo $rowcountneu ?></span> 
    <span class="bad"><b class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></b><?php echo $rowcountneg ?></span>
</div>
```

and when I try to use the same code

```
$revposid = $cont['content_id'];
        $pos="SELECT content_id FROM user_content_like WHERE content_id=$revposid";
        if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$pos)){$rowcountpos=mysqli_num_rows($result);}
```

in my other script I have like system, it should show all my likes and under likes total likes of the post but when I use it it shows unlimited amount of data, i have no idea why. Here's the **full** code, I would appreciate some help or explanation.

```
<?php $ususername = $_GET['user_username'];$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_username='$ususername'";$usresult = mysqli_query($_db,$sql);?>
<?php if( ! mysqli_num_rows($usresult) ) {
            echo " Ooops? <br> <br>User <b>".$_GET["user_username"]."</b> doesn't exist.";
        } else {
            while($usrow = mysqli_fetch_array($usresult,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {?>







<?php


$current_user = $usrow['user_id'];
if ($_db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $_db->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_content_like WHERE user_id=$current_user ORDER BY date_added DESC;";
$result = $_db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$content_id = $row['content_id'];


$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE content_id=$content_id";
$result1 = $_db->query($sql1);      

    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == $usrow['user_id']) {$output = '
    <button type="button" class="unlike_button" onclick="unlike(this);" name="like_button" data-content_id="'.$row["content_id"].'" ><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    ';} else {
        $output = '';
    }


    while($cont = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

        $revposid = $cont['content_id'];
        $pos="SELECT content_id FROM user_content_like WHERE content_id=$revposid";
        if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$pos)){$rowcountpos=mysqli_num_rows($result);}

        echo '
        <div class="community-feed-thread"> 
            <div class="community-icon-thread"></div> 
            <div class="community-comments-thread">'.$output.'</div> 
                <a href="'.$cont["content_id"].'" class="community-title-thread"><h3>'.$cont["title"].'</h3>
                    <span class="likes-desc"> Total likes:  '.$rowcountpos.'</span>
                </a>

        </div>
        ';
    }
}}
    else {
        echo " hmmmmmmmmmmmm.<Br><br>". $usrow["user_username"]." doesn't like anything. ";
    }

$_db->close();
?> 

<?php }}?>
```

[this is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tHtF.png)

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7bK1.png)

Comment: I think you are struggling with both English and SQL. Why are you hauling all the data back to PHP in order to count the rows rather than just `select count(*) from....`. The result you get cannot possibly be "unlimited". Why are you joining your results in PHP (worse still, in a nested loop) rather than writing a query with a join?

Comment: yes, i am learning php now, kinda beginner.. Just trying to understand things.

Comment: got it working with COUNT. Thank you. searched for some help on google and found what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your re-using the same variable for different result sets in the code...

```
$result = $_db->query($sql);
```

and

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($_db,$pos))
```

You will need to ensure you only use the variable name once or it may have side effects in other loops.

Comment: All you need to do is rename the second `$result` to something else - `$result2` or anything.  Remember to update any uses of this value as well.